# Is this a virus?

Tags: malware

I have been getting this ad popup for the last few months(green banner on the left).
It happens on some web sites but not all.

Is this a malware infection on my Mac or the web host being compromised issue? How do I remove it if it is my Mac being infected?

[image]

Comment: Check your safari extensions. Could be adware addons.

Comment: & run [Adware Medic](http://www.adwaremedic.com/index.php)

Comment: It's not Safari extension. I only have a few legitimate extensions activated.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that your ISP is doing ad-injections.